# How to simulate ctrl+c to copy file in bash

Tags: java, linux, bash

I hope copy file entry in cli and paste it with ctrl+v in file explorer, i find following java code can do it, how to do it in linux shell?

```
public static void putFileToSystemClipboard(final File fileOut) throws Exception {
        final Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        final ClipboardOwner clipboardOwner = null;

        final Transferable transferable = new Transferable() {
            public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(final DataFlavor flavor) {
                return false;
            }
            public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
                return new DataFlavor[] { DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor, DataFlavor.stringFlavor };
            }
            public Object getTransferData(final DataFlavor flavor) {
                if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
                    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(fileOut.getAbsolutePath());
                    return list;
                }
                if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                    return fileOut.getAbsolutePath();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        clipboard.setContents(transferable, clipboardOwner);
    }
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/288320/whats-like-osxs-pbcopy-for-linux

Comment: @ewcz, I know xclip, but i only put string to clipboard, see my java code, i put file to my clipboard, and then i can paste(ctrl+v) in file explorer, that's diff

Comment: as far as I understand your code, it puts the absolute path in the clipboard? in that case perhaps `readlink -f your_file | xclip -selection clipboard` should work - here `readlink -f` returns the absolute path of `your_file`...

Comment: @ewcz, no, my code doesn't copy absolute path, my code work like file explorer > select file > hit ctrl+c

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

**in short**

run following code will copy "/tmp/file-to-clip/smth" and then i can hit ctrl+v to paste it in Thunar

```
public class FileToClip {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final File file = new File("/tmp/file-to-clip/smth");
        System.out.println("copy " + file.toString());
        new FileToClip().toClip(file);

        Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public void toClip(final File f) throws Exception {
        final Clipboard clip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        final ClipboardOwner clipboardOwner = null;

        final Transferable transferable = new Transferable() {
            public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(final DataFlavor flavor) {
                return false;
            }

            public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
                return new DataFlavor[]{DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor, DataFlavor.stringFlavor, gcf};
            }

            public Object getTransferData(final DataFlavor flavor) {
                if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
                    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    return list;
                }

                if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                    return f.getAbsolutePath();
                }

                if (flavor.equals(gcf)) {
                    String p = "copy\n" +
                            "file://" + f.getAbsolutePath();
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(p.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        clip.setContents(transferable, clipboardOwner);
    }

    DataFlavor gcf = createDataFlavor("x-special/gnome-copied-files", null, true);

    public static DataFlavor createDataFlavor(@NotNull final String mimeType, @Nullable final Class<?> klass, final boolean register) {
        try {
            final DataFlavor flavor =
                    klass != null ? new DataFlavor(mimeType + ";class=" + klass.getName(), null, klass.getClassLoader()) : new DataFlavor(mimeType);

            if (register) {
                final FlavorMap map = SystemFlavorMap.getDefaultFlavorMap();
                if (map instanceof SystemFlavorMap) {
                    ((SystemFlavorMap) map).addUnencodedNativeForFlavor(flavor, mimeType);
                }
            }

            return flavor;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**for detail**

all code can be found in intellij idea [this source file](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/PsiCopyPasteManager.java)(see #getTransferData)

- how to find dataflavor like "x-special/gnome-copied-files"?
  according `man xclip`

> -t, -target
>
> specify a particular data format using the given target atom.  With -o the special target atom name "TARGETS" can be used to get a list of valid target atoms for this selec‐
>             tion.  For more information about target atoms refer to ICCCM section 2.6.2

so i can do following to get target(dataflavor in java)

- hit ctrl+c in gui(file explorer, or code ide)
- xclip -selection clipboard -o -t TARGETS

the output like following:

```
UTF8_STRING
TEXT
STRING
text/plain;charset=UTF-16
text/plain;charset=UTF-8
text/plain;charset=UTF-16BE
text/plain;charset=UTF-16LE
text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
text/plain;charset=US-ASCII
text/plain
FILE_NAME
text/uri-list
text/uri-list;charset=UTF-16
text/uri-list;charset=UTF-8
text/uri-list;charset=UTF-16BE
text/uri-list;charset=UTF-16LE
text/uri-list;charset=ISO-8859-1
text/uri-list;charset=US-ASCII
x-special/gnome-copied-files
```

**return to my question**, if i copy file in cli and paste it in gui, i need to

- make swing or javafx background app(with notification icon)
- cli control this app with socket
- make app autostart on system startup(most linux has this func)